# Function for plotting and saving igraph objects skips list elements when using lapply

Tags: r, jpeg, igraph, lapply

I have a list of network objects and I would like to go through the list, plot each network and save the plot to my working directory.

```
# creating list of networks
networks <- list()
networks[[1]] <- graph(c("A","B"))
networks[[2]] <- graph(c("C","D"))
networks[[3]] <- graph(c("E","F"))
```

Expected Output that I would like to save to the working directory:

```
# looking at plots
plot(networks[[1]])
plot(networks[[2]])
plot(networks[[3]])
```

As my list is rather long and in the original example I need to pass down some initial parameters, I would like to have a function that plots and saves each network and then `lapply()` it to the list. Here´s what I tried:

```
# generating and saving plots automatically
Plotter <- function(network){

        # Generate some random number so plots don´t get overwritten
        Rand <- runif(1,0,100000)

        # setting seed
        set.seed(123)

        # set up picture device
        jpeg(paste(Rand,"NetworkPlot.jpg",sep=""),
             width = 800,
             height = 800,
             units = "px",
             quality = 100)

        # plotting the network
        plot(network)

        # saving to wd
        dev.off()

}

# Applying function to list of networks
lapply(networks,Plotter)
```

What I would expect are three different plots in my working directory. However, if I go to the wd, I only see the first and the last plots.

At first I thought it might be an unlikely coincidence when the same Rand gets picked and the file is overwritten. But I tried several times and it happens every time.

Comment: Usually `set.seed` must precede random number calls. But for your case, you do not need even want to set seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the way that you generated the names,  it is not so unlikely that the same numbers will be generated twice. In fact, it is guaranteed.   Your code says:

```
# Generate some random number so plots don´t get overwritten
Rand <- runif(1,0,100000)

# setting seed
set.seed(123)
```

The first time it is executed, it will generate one random number between 0 and 100000. Then you set the random seed to 123. The second time that you execute the function, it will generate a number starting from the seed 123. Then reset the seed to 123.  Every subsequent time,  it will generate a number from the random seed 123 and overwrite the all previous results except the first. So you get the first and the last. Just delete the line that sets the seed and you will get all different numbers and therefore different file names.

If you want to test this,  leave your code as is,  but add the line

```
write(paste0(Rand, "\n"), stderr())
```

just after you generate Rand.

Comment: Interesting! I was assuming that setting the seed was only happening in the function environment but it seems to be a global variable if it gets carried over to the next call of the function? Definitly good to know! Thank you.

Comment: @JuKo ... Not quite true. Since `lapply` is a loop, you are iterating the function multiple times and hence setting the same seed number multiple times. You can pass different numbers into `set.seed()` and return different random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a random number which is seeded after first run, use the index number of the list by iterating across the length of *networks*.

Specifically, consider calling `lapply` with `seq_along` and so passes integers into defined function which will be used for: 1) distinct file names and 2) index your list: `networks[[##]]`. Plus, if you have an issue with anyone plot, you know which item is the issue!

```
# generating and saving plots automatically
Plotter <- function(n){    
    # set up picture device
    jpeg(paste0("NetworkPlot_", n, ".jpg"),
         width = 800,
         height = 800,
         units = "px",
         quality = 100)

    # plotting the network
    plot(networks[[n]])

    # saving to wd
    dev.off()    
}

lapply(seq_along(networks), Plotter)
```

Likewise, a named list can work in same aspect where strings are passed into function:

```
# NAMING ITEMS: n1, n2, n3, ...
networks <- setNames(networks, paste0("n", seq_along(networks)))

# OUTPUT PLOTS
networks$n1
networks$n2
networks$n3
...

# SAVE PLOTS TO DISK
lapply(names(networks), Plotter)
```

Comment: Great! I was wondering on how to improve that part too but thought it was only possible using for loops which I tried to avoid. The solution with `seq_along()` is nice, thanks!